# ServiceStack MQ (version > 4.0.54) GlobalMessageResponseFilters are not invoked

Tags: servicestack

Problem:
  GlobalMessageResponseFilters are not invoked for MQ server.
  ServiceStack version > v4.0.54.

According to [documentation](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters), MQ servers can register global message
handlers to be invoked before/after request.
However, the function 'ApplyMessageResponseFilters' is not called.
Here's the [link](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/v4.0.62/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs#L257-L270) to source code.

As a workaround, I've been using GlobalResponseFilters callback.
It seems to be that either the documentation is out of date or there
may be a regression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a regression that's now resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/2c008a9c13c30fd44d7eb1b7a1cfa6a06dde3f3d).

This change is available from v4.5.1 that's now [available on MyGet](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/MyGet).